# place image in div with object-fit:cover

Tags: html, css

I have a div that I have an image in with object-fit:cover that fits just how I want it but I cannot place text over it. If I put it in as a div bakcground it does not resize the same. Is there anyway of placing it in the div as a background but still use object-fit:cover. Many thanks

I am using the following:

```css
.main {
      -webkit-filter: blur(0.2px);
      -moz-filter: blur(0.2px);
      -o-filter: blur(0.2px);
      -ms-filter: blur(0.2px);
      filter: blur(0.2px);
      border:0;
      padding:0;
        width:100%;
        height:560px;
        object-fit:cover;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid main" style="margin-top: 0px;">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1213997/pexels-photo-1213997.jpeg" class="main" alt="mainbg" width="400" height="320">
    <div class="main-text">text here</div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for `background-size: cover`?

Comment: Yes cover the same way as it is and to show the same as it does already but as a background so I can add text over it, thanks

Comment: Why not just use it as a background for the parent div, any text inside the div will show over it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the image as the background image. In conbination with other rules, you will have what you expect.

```
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1213997/pexels-photo-1213997.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Hope this helps :>

```css
.main {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0.2px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0.2px);
  -o-filter: blur(0.2px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0.2px);
  filter: blur(0.2px);
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 560px;
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1213997/pexels-photo-1213997.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.main-text {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid main" style="margin-top: 0px;">
  <div class="main-text">text here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, it is not exactly as before it is slightly off center but its good enough thankyou

Comment: Glad it help out. Hope you can upvote or accept if this solved your problem.  :)\

Answer (score 1):

```css
.main {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0.2px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0.2px);
  -o-filter: blur(0.2px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0.2px);
  filter: blur(0.2px);
  border:0;
  padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:560px;
    object-fit:cover;
}
.main-text{
position:absolute;
top:50px;
left:150px;}
```

```html
With the HTML :

<div class="container-fluid main" style="margin-top: 0px;">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRL9rsCJmYG8L6mb5mN_geyDWtUNhKw0AIG6lJ3p7YGg7SxyHWb" class="main" alt="mainbg" width="400" height="320">
<div class="main-text">text here text heretext heretext here</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer, and nice that you are helping! Consider adding some explanation or commenting your code.  code only answers are not as useful to future visitors.  There's enough code here it's not immediately obvious what you've changed / why it works...

Comment: thats what i added: .main-text{
position:absolute;
top:50px;
left:150px;}

Answer (score 1):

I have not changed the `object-fit` property. I have just altered the `.main-text` to be positioned above the image. Is this what you expected?

```css
.main {
      -webkit-filter: blur(0.2px);
      -moz-filter: blur(0.2px);
      -o-filter: blur(0.2px);
      -ms-filter: blur(0.2px);
      filter: blur(0.2px);
      border:0;
      padding:0;
        width:100%;
        height:560px;
        object-fit:cover;
    }
.main-text{
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid main" style="margin-top: 0px;">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1213997/pexels-photo-1213997.jpeg" class="main" alt="mainbg" width="400" height="320">
    <div class="main-text">text here</div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you are just trying to get the text on top of image at the center, you can try the following with position absolute for the text

```css
.main {
      -webkit-filter: blur(0.2px);
      -moz-filter: blur(0.2px);
      -o-filter: blur(0.2px);
      -ms-filter: blur(0.2px);
      filter: blur(0.2px);
      border:0;
      padding:0;
      width:100%;
      height:560px;
      object-fit:cover;
      position: relative;
    }
    .main-text {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    color: white;
    font-size: 3rem;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid main" style="margin-top: 0px;">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1213997/pexels-photo-1213997.jpeg" class="main" alt="mainbg" width="400" height="320">
    <div class="main-text">text here</div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
```